# What is the counterpart of a consultant?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

Someone who is consulted is a consultant, but what is his counterpart called?  In other words, what do you call the person who consults them?

*Asker* sounds informal, *consulter* doesn't pass my spell check, *help-seeker* sounds too pathological.

Is there a sensible opposite?

Comment: In most uses, a client is the one seeking a consultation but I wouldn't consider _client_ to be an antonym of _consultant_.

Comment: Still a good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: There’s *advisee*

Comment: Why do people think every noun must have an antonym? What is the antonym of *brick*? Of *diatom*? Of *aspirin*?

Comment: You are misusing the term "antonym".

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite of a consultant be someone that you would not go to for advice under any circumstances?

Comment: @Sherlock: The term *antonym* is conceptual intrinsically. There is no distinction between it and what you term a "conceptual antonym." I think you would be better served by describing the relationship between *consultant* and the word you're seeking as *counterpart* or *complement*, not *antonym*.

Answer (score 1):

**"consultant"** is too broad a term.

> A consultant (from Latin: consultare "to deliberate") is a professional who provides expert advice[1] in a particular area such as security (electronic or physical), management, education, accountancy, law, regulatory compliance, human resources, marketing (and public relations), finance, health care, engineering, science or any of many other specialized fields. A consultant is usually an expert or an experienced professional in a specific field and has a wide knowledge of the subject matter.  from [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consultant)

A medical doctor can be a consultant. In this case, one who is seeking medical advice, would be called **"patient"**.

A lawyer, as well as several other professionals, can also be a consultant. Here, the person seeking help or advice is usually called **"client"**.

> - patient (noun) - One who receives medical attention, care, or treatment. [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/patient)
> - client (noun) -  The party for which professional services are rendered, as by an attorney.  [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/client)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the -er(-or)/-ee juxtaposition conveys the relationships you are after, like in payer/payee, employer/employee, tutor/tutee, advisor/advisee,

At variance with this usage placing the -ee people at the *receiving* side, some [sources](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/consultee) indicate that a consultee is the person *giving* consultancy, that is the consultant, or in restricted sense, the consultor. So you find out a kind of harsh spot.

The consultee does receive questions thus. Then, beside the other suggestions given here, I would give a chance to **inquirer** or **enquirer** as per
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquirer. This sounds less informal than asker.

As a note, do not trust to spellcheckers to test the existence of a word, since they are often based on abridged dictionaries. Dictionaries are not the same, also; for example [this one](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=consultee&s=t) does not have any key for consultee, unlike the other two cited in this answer.

Disclaimer: not a mother tongue. 
Please comment/edit after downvoting so I can learn from it.